# NetBeans: LESSコンパイラが動いていません

Tags: netbeans

[こちら](http://worktoolsmith.com/2013/12/6613/)の説明の通りに`NetBeans`のため`LESS`コンパイラを導入しましたが、
下記のようなメッセージが出ています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

そもそも、node.exeのようなファイルは存在していません。

先ず、説明通り`C:/`に展開してみましたが、アクセスに関係がある問題かなと思って、
別のドライブにしましたが、何も変わっていません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ディレクトリ名が `less.js-windows-master` ということは、Githubの Download ZIP ボタンでダウンロードしましたね？

リポジトリのトップページの説明にもありますが、利用者はリリース版のzipをダウンロードする必要があります。説明のInstall節に書かれているリンクから飛ぶか、リポジトリ上部の 8 releases と書かれたあたりをクリックします。

https://github.com/duncansmart/less.js-windows/releases

あなたがダウンロードしたzipはReleasesページで言うところの `Source code (.zip)` ですが、ダウンロードするだけで使えるようにビルドされたものは `less.js-windows-v2.6.1.zip` 等なので、こちらをダウンロードしてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます、これで解決完了です。